# getting error while creating subfolder in Directory python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
import os
#Folders Creation
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('I:\DATA\Train'):
    print('The current folder is ' + folderName)
    
    for filename in filenames:
        filename=os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        os.makedirs(filename, exist_ok=True)
        print(filename)

    print('')
#Sub Folders Creation
path="C:\DATA"
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    print('The current folder is ' + folderName)
    
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + folderName + ': ' + subfolder)
        mypath = os.path.join(path,str(subfolder))
        os.chdir(mypath)
        os.getcwd()
        os.makedirs("test",exist_ok=True)
        os.makedirs("train",exist_ok=True)
        os.close
        
    print('')
```

This code works but also throw error but when i create test and train folder on path then error goes away how to solve this without creating test and train in path

## Getting this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\DATA\\test'
```

Comment: what is your python version? 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ 3.6

Comment: Can you change to os.makedirs(os.path.join(mypath, "test"),exist_ok=True)? The chdir did not work since it is creating the folder on C:\\DATA\\test instead of C:\DATA\Bartosz Firyn\test

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ yes this os.makedirs(os.path.join(mypath, "test"),exist_ok=True) works but also create test and train folder in C:\\DATA

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ i dont want to create test and train folder in C:\\DATA only want to create test and train folder in all folders in C:\\DATA

Comment: The first problem is `mypath = os.path.join(path,str(subfolder))` That `path` is always `C:\DATA`, not the parent of `subfolder`—you need `folderName` for that. That's why it's throwing errors—you're trying to `chdir` to `C:\DATA\Deep` whenever you need to `chdir` to `C:\DATA\Shallow\Medium\Deep`.

Comment: The second problem is that, as your last comment says, you're avoiding creating these folders in `C:\DATA` itself—but that's exactly what the error message you get later is complaining about, that you didn't create `C:\DATA\test`. I don't know what you're doing that raises that exception, but whatever it is, either you're calling something wrong so it's asking for directories it shouldn't be, or you're calling something right and you were wrong to skip creating those directories because they're necessary.

Comment: @abarnert check this log https://text-share.com/view/cd0be294

Comment: @abarnert there are folders in C:/data what i am doing is creating test and train folder in every directory of C:/data except C:/data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below. The lines os.chdir(mypath) and os.getcwd() seems not working for you.

```
for subfolder in subfolders:
    print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + folderName + ': ' + subfolder)
    mypath1 = os.path.join(path,str(subfolder),"test")
    mypath2 = os.path.join(path,str(subfolder),"train")
    os.makedirs(mypath1,exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(mypath2,exist_ok=True)
    os.close
```

Comment: There is no error but test and train folders are still created on C:\data and inside test and train there is also sub test and train folder

Comment: Thank You for error fix i use temporary solution of extra test and train folder 
import shutil
shutil.rmtree("C:/DATA/test", ignore_errors=True)
shutil.rmtree("C:/DATA/train", ignore_errors=True)

Answer (score -1):

Try to change  '\' , and use use '/' for the path.

Comment: Can you give me more information about the error? Is that the only message that python returns to you?

Comment: I check the log and I sow that you still having '\'                     "SUBFOLDER OF C:/DATA\Bartosz Firyn: test"  . Can you try doing something like this: mypath.replace('\', '/') before "os.chdir(mypath)"

Comment: check now i changed '\' with '/' but still the same error https://text-share.com/view/cd0be294